# Laravel: Error with like system implementation

Tags: php, html, laravel, laravel-blade

I am quite new to laravel so this might be silly mistake but I just can't figure out why it gives me this error. Right so on my website users can create posts and other users can like those posts. However, my implementation of the like system throws the following error:

```
ErrorException (E_ERROR)
Method Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection::likes does not exist. (View: C:\xampp\htdocs\eventcw\resources\views\eventspage.blade.php)
```

This is my post controller method in charge of the likes:

```
public function postLikePost($post_id){
    $loggedin_user = Auth::user()->id;
    $like_user = Like::where(['user_id' => $loggedin_user, 'post_id' => $post_id])->first();
    if(empty($like_user->user_id)){
        $user_id = Auth::user()->id;
        $post_id = $post_id;

        $like = new Like;

        $like->user_id = $user_id;
        $like->post_id = $post_id;
        $like->save();
        return  redirect()->route('events');

    }else{
        return  redirect()->route('events');
    }

}
```

My database relations seem fine,

here is my Like model:

```
namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Like extends Model
{
    public function user(){
        return $this->belongsTo('App\User');
    }

    public function post(){
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Post');
    }
}
```

Here is my likes table migration:

```
    Schema::create('likes', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->integer('post_id');
        $table->integer('user_id');
        $table->timestamps();
    });
```

Here is my post view:

```
<section class="row posts">
    @foreach($posts as $post)
        <div class="col-md-2 col-md-offset-3">
            <article class="post">
                <p>{{ $post->body }}</p>
                <div class="info">Posted by {{ $post->user->first_name }} {{ $post->user->last_name }} on {{ $post->created_at }}</div>
                <p>This post has {{ $posts->likes()->count() }} likes </p>
                <a href="{{ route('like') }}" class="post-item">Like</a>|
            </article>
        </div>
    @endforeach
</section>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error indicates you are calling `likes()` directly on a Collection.

`$posts` is the collection, which you are iterating over in your blade template.

Change `{{ $posts->likes()->count() }}` to `{{ $post->likes()->count() }}`

Comment: The page loads up now, but I'm getting another error now:  Symfony \ Component \ HttpKernel \ Exception \ MethodNotAllowedHttpException
No message, happens when I click like.

Comment: Does the likes() method exist/work? How about count()? Try to debug/isolate, if you cant figure out, make a new question.

Comment: Yes, it works cause it says 0 likes when I load the web page. It gives the error when I click like.